# Ms Word Vba Command Button Insert Text on Word Doc

Tags: vba, button, ms-word, command, simple-form

on click of the Command Button on MS WORD VBA FORM, a specific Text has to be inserted on the same MS Word Document on the place where the blinking cursor/Selection cursor is placed.

can someone place help me.

Comment: Post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Me.Hide
With ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection

    .TypeText Text:="Your text here"

End With
End Sub
```